# Laravel Eloquent: Query complex relations over multiple models

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

**Update: Solved,** problem was not eloquent, it's quite efficient in using multiple scopes across multiple models. I had an output in my view which would query for each resident the occupations, room and floor. This led to over 2600 queries for ~200 residents and was the reason for my performance drop. I now use **eager loading** to get all occupations and rooms with the first query by adding `->with(['occupation.room'])`.

I have a model which consists of residents who live in rooms. Those rooms are rented out for a certain period of time which is why we have a table occupations. This table determines which resident lives where.
Here's a visualisation: [image: Relationmodel]

My problem is that Eloquent has no efficient way to determine all residents living house X or all residents on floor Y (see floor model for house attr).

I am using query scopes on Room:

```
public function scopeHouse($query, $house) {
    return $query->whereHas('floor', function($q) use($house) {
        $q->where('house', $house);
    });
}
```

On Occupation:

```
public function scopeHouse($query, $house) {
    return $query->whereHas('room', function($q) use($house) {
        $q->house($house);
    });
}
```

And Resident:

```
public function scopeHouse($query, $house) {
    return $query->whereHas('occupation', function($q) use($house) {
        $q->house($house);
    });
}
```

Which is obviously not very efficient. I could just query all occupations and then query rooms and residents individually but that would destroy eloquents nice fluent api.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can query nested relation too. ->whereHas('occupation.room.floor', function(){});, I don't know if it helps you or not.

Comment: I will try, but I think not. My current approach is to use joins to reduce the amount of queries.

Comment: Update: Apparently the problem was not using multiple scopes. It's quite fast and efficient. The performance drop came from querying the room for every single resident in the view. I will now use a more efficient way by collecting all occupations and rooms together (`->with(['occupation', 'occupation.room'])`) and then use PHP to choose the current occupation and extract the room from there.

Comment: @cgross Yes, eager loading will save you tons of queries in this situation.